# How to Alternate Between Vertically and Horizontally Displayed Footnotes in the Same Document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, footnotes, paragraphs, footmisc

I have discovered that if I use `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`in the preamble, all of the footnotes are displayed in a horizontal (paragraph) fashion---which is what I want sometimes.

On the other hand, if I use `\usepackage{footmisc}` in the preamble, then all of the footnotes are delineated in the standard vertical fashion---which is sometimes what I want in the document I am working on.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to alternate between the two types of footnotes as, of course, a `\usepackage` must appear in the preamble only.

Please consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}
A sentence.\footnote{Footnote.}
A sentence.\footnote{Another footnote.}

\vskip 15pt

Now I would like to switch to vertically displayed footnotes.\footnote{This is a longer footnote and so I would like to display it in the standard (vertical) manner.}

\vskip 10pt

Similarly,\footnote{This is another long footnote and would like to present it in a vertical manner.}

\vskip 10pt

Another sentence.\footnote{And I would like to be able to switch back to paragraph footnotes if I should encounter a series of short footnotes within the same document.} 
\end{document}
```

which gives the footnote display:

[image]

It seems that what I would like to be able to do should be abe to be done simply, but I have been unable to figure out how. Your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report`, and `article`) provides a variety of footnote styles.

```
% footnoteprob2.tex SE 584269

\documentclass[article]{memoir}

%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\paragraphfootnotes
A sentence.\footnote{Footnote.}
A sentence.\footnote{Another footnote.}

\vskip 15pt

\plainfootnotes
Now I would like to switch to vertically displayed footnotes.\footnote{This is a longer footnote and so I would like to display it in the standard (vertical) manner.}

\vskip 10pt

Similarly,\footnote{This is another long footnote and would like to present it in a vertical manner.}

\vskip 10pt

\paragraphfootnotes
Another sentence.\footnote{And I would like to be able to switch back to paragraph footnotes if I should encounter a series of short footnotes within the same document.} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of potential hiccups. There may be odd effects, as shown, if there is more than one footnote style on a page. The `memoir` `article` option assumes `\chapter` etc. but treats `\chapter` as `\section`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this works nicely. There has always to be a space before the notescommand.

```
      \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
    \newcommand{\vertical}[1]{\blfootnote{-----\hfill}\hskip-0.3em\footnote{\vtop{#1\vskip\baselineskip}\hfill }}
    \newcommand{\horizontal}[1]{\hskip-0.3em\footnote{#1}\hskip0.2em}
    \begin{document}
In diesem Text \horizontal{Erste horizontale Fußnote} sind Fußnoten enthalten, Er soll zeigen, wie horizontale \horizontal{Zweite horizontale Fußnote} und vertikale Fußnoten gleichzeitig \horizontal{Dritte horizontale Fußnote} verwirklicht \horizontal{Vierte horizontale Fußnote}werden können\horizontal{Fünfte horizontale Fußnote}.

Hier kommt jetzt eine vertikale Fußnote dazu \vertical{Erste vertikale Fußnote}. Dann geht es im Text weiter und man wird sehen, wie sich alles entwickelt \vertical{Zweite vertikale Fußnote}. Gibt es noch Probleme, so soll man sie lösen \vertical{Dritte vertikale Fußnote}\dots
In diesem Text \horizontal{Horizontale Fußnote} sind Fußnoten enthalten, Er soll zeigen, wie horizontale \horizontal{Horizontale Fußnote} und vertikale Fußnoten gleichzeitig \horizontal{Horizontale Fußnote} verwirklicht \horizontal{Horizontale Fußnote}werden können\horizontal{Horizontale Fußnote}.\vertical{Vierte vertikale Fußnote}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Does not work in any case

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. This works nicely as both types of footnotes are under the same horizontal bar. As you pointed out---there is a horizontal stretch between the words in the horizontal footnotes; Any idea what may be causing that? Please update your answer if you figure that out. Thanks again.

Comment: Does not work, if the horizontal notes do not fill the lines, But, as always, there will be a solution.

Comment: When I ran it---it noticed that the 15th and 16th horizontal footnotes (only two on the last line) did not have a horizontal strecth between `Another' and `footnote'; but maybe that's because there were no more footnotes following them.

Comment: @mlchristians I have updated the answer, I think it works.

Comment: What happened to the long footnote? When I run the code I get a series of dashes that seem to be separators. I think your other answer was better as it only required a correction to the large space between the two words in the short notes.

Comment: Please post an example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Suggestion---just run your code and post the output.

Comment: The dashes should show how it works, they are not needed. Another answer below. You may switch between horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 1):

```
      \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

    \newcommand{\vertical}[1]{\blfootnote{\hskip1em\hfill}\hskip-0.3em\footnote{\vtop {#1\vskip\baselineskip}\hfill }}
    \newcommand{\horizontal}[1]{\hskip-0.3em\footnote{#1}\hskip0.2em}
\newcommand{\paranote}[2]{\ifnum #1=1 \horizontal{#2}\fi\ifnum #1=2 \vertical{#2}\fi}
    \begin{document}
A sentence.\paranote{1}{Footnote.}
A sentence.\paranote{1}{Another footnote.}

Now I would like to switch to vertically displayed footnotes.\paranote{2}{This is a longer footnote and so I would like to display it in the standard (vertical) manner.}

Similarly,\paranote{2}{This is another long footnote and would like to present it in a vertical manner.}

\vskip 10pt

Another sentence.\paranote{1}{And I would like to be able to switch back to paragraph footnotes if I should encounter a series of short footnotes within the same document.} 
Another sentence.\paranote{1}{And I would like to be able to switch back to paragraph footnotes if I should encounter a series of short footnotes within the same document.} 

\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the shift to the right? It does not shift on my computer. Besides:  How may I post my PDF? As an image?

Comment: That's how it came out on mine. Please feel free to replace the picture with yours.

Comment: Also, please notice how the footnotemarks are over the periods. With your code, I tried to make them appear more normally spaced, but was not able to. Are you able to adjust the positioning of the footnotemarks? Thanks.

Comment: You can define the spaces between the text and the footnotemark by adjusting the \hskip before the \footnote command( \hskip0.2em\footnote) It is different in horizontal and vertical notes.Still, it is not as nice as it should be.

Comment: Hey! Why did I get unupvotes for those nice answers?